# Html table with transpose facility

Tags: html, rotation, transpose

I need to design a html table where I want to facilitate user with transpose feature(change columns to row and rows to columns),hide rows from table.
How can I do it?

Comment: What language/environment are you using? Add the corresponding tags. (And don't use the [tag:table] tag.)

Comment: I am using backbone.js and html5.I want to transpose html table.Is it possible in html5?I am newbie in both technologies..appreciate any help..